# redux-form submit validation: Not working with jQuery Deferred (Uncaught SubmissionError)

Tags: jquery, reactjs, redux, deferred, redux-form

I'm trying to get the submit validation of redux-form to work with jQuery Deferred Promises instead of the native JavaScript Promise.

I changed the example from the
[submit validation redux-form documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/submitValidation/)

```
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form'

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

function submit(values) {
  return sleep(1000) // simulate server latency
    .then(() => {
        throw new SubmissionError({ username: 'User does not exist', _error: 'Login failed!' })
      }
    })
}
```

I updated the sleep() function in order to return a jQuery Deferred Promise:

```
const sleep = ms => {
    const deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(() => deferred.resolve(), ms);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

But now the example is not working any more, I'm getting an **Uncaught SubmissionError: Submit Validation Failed** instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?